# When printing a webpage, how can I make a button that reloads the page before printing?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that has dynamic graphs. They are responsive and adjust to the screen width when rotating the screen.

I made my link like this: `<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>`

However when I click the button on a mobile device, the graphs don't resize. The rest of the page is as expected.

This led me to thinking that maybe, if I could refresh the page before the print preview, my graphs would be all good.

So I tried this on my body tag: `<body onbeforeprint="location.reload()">`

This didn't do the trick either. My graphs didn't show at all. I'm also on the edge on my knowledge with that. I didn't actually print it, just looked at the preview.

How can I resolve this so that my graphs get rendered again for printing? After clicking a print button.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom function for that reason and attach that to your button. This function put information to the localstorage, and after reload if the information is there, then immediatelly remove it, and start printing.

```js
function refreshAndPrint() {
  localStorage.setItem("print", "that");
  location.reload();
}

const printIt = localStorage.getItem("print");
if (printIt) {
  localStorage.removeItem("print");
  window.print();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="refreshAndPrint()">Print this page</button>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. I tried that to no avail sadly. It opens the print dialog but the graphs are still tiny.

Comment: That refreshes the page before the print dialog opens. So leads to the same result. Maybe my thinking is flawed.